# How to enable tls 1.2 on jdk 1.6 on mac

Tags: performance

I am facing some issues while connecting to some of the endpoints. For example, in our application, we are using Paypal as one of our payment methods. But Paypal only supports the connection with tls 1.2 protocol.That being said we are using jdk 1.6 in our local, which is at present restricting me for the connection. I know Oracle has released the tls 1.2 support patch for Windows and Unix. But could not find one for mac. I did try the java 6 which is available in apple but that's also failing.

Comment: Java 6 is EOL since 2013. Upgrade to Java 8, which has TLSv1.2 on by default. Or if you have commercial support from Oracle, ask them, they have a solution for Java 6.

Comment: There is no patch for TLS1.2 as such; there were paid updates for 6 and 7 that have various enhancements including that. When it was free-beer (through 6u45) Sun/Oracle java6 did not support Mac, only Linux Solaris Windows; while they _could_ have added this in the paid era, that would be a pretty major change. FWIW the release notes (which _are_ public) for 6 don't contain the string "OSX" or "macosx" while those for 7 and 8 do. If you can install and use third-party providers, BouncyCastle now has a 'bctls' provider that can replace JSSE and support TLS1.2 I _believe_ back to j5.

Comment: Let me get this straight:  you're planning on doing online payments via PayPal using a Java platform that hasn't had a security update in over 5 years?!?!?!  Seriously?!?!  Is your corporate counsel aware of this technical decision?  Have you had lawyers review whatever agreement your company has with PayPal in light of this planned use of an old, known-to-be insecure platform to see what kind of liability that opens you up to?

Comment: Known CVE vulnerabilities in Java 1.6u45:  https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=93&product_id=19117&version_id=147025&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=3&trc=70&sha=fbda9eb29f864b063d8f2cd61b583f8599e1e90b  Note that there are 70 known security vulnerabilities, of which fully **22 have the maximum 10.0 severity.**  Using Java 1.6u45 to do online payment processing is nothing short of professional malfeasance.